# CiviCRM Profile / new contact: is there a way to automatically update the Source Field?

Tags: profile

I set up a Profile which collects contact information for new supporters. It automatically creates a new contact record, but I'd like the CiviCRM Source field to be automatically filled in (e.g. Petition Signer). Also, it would be nice if it automatically triggered a thank you email. Is there a way to do these things? Thanks much for a great product!!

Comment: agree that if a contact is created via a Profile, that the Profile as 'Source" would be useful

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal, Webforms give you full control over these things.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, we're using CiviCRM 4.5.8 and WordPress...