# New Contacts and Profiles - Is there a way to update the source field?

Tags: profile, form-snippets

We use some profiles - some of which are embedded on external sites. It would be helpful if the Contact Source could be updated to reflect the source of the contact being the profile.

I know this can be done using Drupal and WebForm - but I am specifically interested in Profiles.

[This has been asked before](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/civicrm-profile-new-contact-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-the-source) - but its been a few years - so hopefully we will get some fresh answers. :)

Answer (score 4):

One option is very similar to this [question/answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3863/how-can-i-assign-tag-when-certain-profiles-are-submitted).

Add contacts created by the profile to a group and use CiviRules to populate the source field when the contact is added to the group - it's not "clean" and honestly a PR/extension to allow profiles to set any field using tokens (including a token for "profile name".) would probably be a better long-term solution.

Alternatively a PR to CiviRules to directly support profiles.